# What is the Javascript event that triggers when you drag a file from your desktop to your browser

Tags: jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, gmail

I'm trying to implement a file upoload system similar to gmail's. I've already done all the Fileupload / AJAX issue and it works perfect. The only problem that I have is User Feedback.

For example.. in gmail, when you drag a file to your browser (assuming IE9+ user), there's an area that pops up, letting you drop the file in. I think it is some kind of JavaScript event that is captured by a framework (let's say Jquery), that allows me to make some cool animations on the drop area.

My question is simple.. What event should I capture to do this? Any ideas? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main event is just `drop`.

You will also need to handle `dragenter` and `dragleave` otherwise the drop action will just cause a load of the dropped files.  You may optionally also watch `dragover`.

I have some code that registers these handlers, like so:

```
var $dz = $('#dropzone');
$dz.on({
    dragenter: dragenter,
    dragleave: dragleave,
    dragover: false,
    drop: drop
});

function dragenter() {
    $dz.addClass('active');
};

function dragleave() {
    $dz.removeClass('active');
};

function drop(e) {
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    if (dt) {
        var files = dt.files;
        ...
    }
    $dz.removeClass('active');
};
```

In this case the `dragenter` and `dragleave` handlers are there just to change the appearance of the drop zone when stuff is being dragged into it.

Comment: Cool! I wish my boss would want this feature.

Comment: Well, this actually kinda work, but only when I pass the dragged item over the drop zone.. I still don't know where the drop zone is.. so I figured.. well. instead of $(element).on.... ill use $("body").on... It triggers well, but when I enter to any other div (lets say that I have my page centred with fixed width, so there´s some empty space on both sides that we might say "is pure body tag"), then it triggers the leave handlers... Ill figure out how to maintain the "enter" all over the page, and only triggers the "leave" when it actually leaves the browser zone entirely. Thanks for the help

Comment: Besides, it kind of sux.. Seems like the event "dragenter" triggers on every pixel the mouse moves.! so lets say I play a nice "shake" effect on the dropzone for 2 secs.. well.. it actually feels like its frozen, cuz it wont stop shakeing as long as i keep moving the mouse.!

Answer (score 3):

It's called `drop`, and the properties you need from the event object will be in the originalEvent property.

```
$(element).on("drop",function(e){
  console.log(e.originalEvent)
});
```

you also need to unbind the dragenter and dragleave on that same element for it to fire the drop event, if I remember correctly.

```
$(element).on("dragenter dragleave", false);
```

Comment: good note about dragenter and dragleave - I have them in my code but had forgotten that they were actually required.

Comment: @Alnitak - Yeah, that threw me for a loop when I first tried to implement this functionality. I ended up trashing the whole idea and going with jquery's drag-&-drop because I'm using a text area and binding to these events messes with the normal use of a textarea.